# How to dynamically generate images and display after the webpage loads in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, react-scripts

I want to images from an array and upon onload of the browser window it gets display on the webpage. this is what I did.

```js
const players = [
    {
     photo: 'img/photo0.jpeg'
    },
    {
     photo: 'img/photo1.jpeg'
    },
    {
     photo: 'img/photo2.jpeg'
    }]

// This is the function I built to do that.
    function() {

      for(i = 0; i < players.lengh; i++;){
      }
    }
```

Comment: may be you can try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access to the `onLoad` method through the `window` object.

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Whatever you want to do on load
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let box = document.querySelector(".box");

      const players = [
        {
          photo: "img/photo0.jpeg",
        },
        {
          photo: "img/photo1.jpeg",
        },
        {
          photo: "img/photo2.jpeg",
        },
      ];

      function displayImages() {
        // Empty the box element so, that if some changes made to this element will reflect new data
        box.innerHTML = ``;
        // create template to show
        let domStr = ``;
        for (let img of players) {
        //dynamic creating images in template str
          domStr += `
                  <img src=${img.photo} width=200 height=200>
                  `;
        }

        // after loop concatenates str with img in loop make it attach with the element
        // document.body.innerHTML = domStr;
        box.innerHTML = domStr;
      }

      //   On window load calling the function
      window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
        displayImages();
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```